# Standard way of handling a user customizable view on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, user-experience

This is a two part question.

Our iPhone application has a screen which needs to be customizable by users.  It is a simple screen with 4-5 customizable slots.  Users will be able to pick from list of wiglets/controls they would like to see in the view.  They should be able to re-order the widgets and  add/remove as they see fit.

Below is a UI mockup showing how a widget screen like this would work.  The user would press and hold anywhere on the screen, and it would go into edit mode, similar to how deleting an app works.  They then have the opportunity to remove an app from the dashboard and add new ones using a tray at the bottom.

1. Is this an appropriate way of handing this type of view on iPhone, if not where would be a good starting point? Any links or views/controls to look at would be appreciated.
2. Certainly, everything described here could be implemented from scratch using UIView as a base, but are there existing views available from Apple that could help me here?

**UI Mockup**

1 - Existing widget
2 - Empty spot available for widget
3 - Available widgets

[image: ui mockup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make each widget a customized UIView subclass, and just add them to the main view as subviews. As far as specific classes, you could use a customized UITableView (with custom UITableViewCells) for the widget drop area. The widget selection area you could easily implement with a custom UIView and four positioned UIViews. You could also consider [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/).

There aren't any standardized view classes that Apple provides for this.